# sql read blob as text

Tags: sql, excel, firebird, powerpivot

I am trying to output a table field named `observation` as text where it is stored as blob. The SQL is

```
select invoice_id, observation from table1
```

The output I am getting is `as.raw(c(0x31, 0xba, 0x20, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4f, 0x4d, 0x4f, 0x20...`

How can I output as text?

Comment: What programming language/framework/driver you use? It seems to be in hex, so one way is to convert it.

Comment: hello I am using MS  Excel making a query via Powerpivot

Comment: Make sure your field type is `BLOB SUB_TYPE 1` (TEXT). 0 means binary and your tool may output it as binary/hex representation. To retrieve data in Excel you may take a look also at ODBC driver.

Comment: Hi, is there a way I can convert the field in the sql query  to  BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 (TEXT) ?

Comment: Its metadata related. Not in a simple data sql query. May try to cast it as `varchar` on the fly, if it will fit in a reasonable length, like: `select cast(T.BLOB_FIELD as varchar(4096) character set UTF8) as BLOB_FIELD
from MYTABLE T` Note `character set` is optional and may need to be adjusted in your context.

Comment: I wonder if it uses ODBC database connection interface, or maybe OLE DB (as in commercial IBProvider.com) or maybe even .Net provider (though I doubt Excel can use it) ?

Comment: I have use CAST to convert and worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving text in a blob, you should make it a `blob sub_type text` (aka `blob sub_type 1`) instead of a `blob` (aka `blob sub_type binary` aka `blob sub_type 0`). Though that is not a guarantee (some Firebird drivers don't distinguish between blob sub types).

To convert a binary blob to a text blob, use

```
select cast(binblob as blob sub_type text character set utf8) from blobtbl
```

or without character set clause:

```
select cast(binblob as blob sub_type text) from blobtbl
```

Alternatively, you could cast to `VARCHAR`, but make sure you specify a long enough varchar to hold the entire value, otherwise you'll get a truncation error. For example:

```
select cast(binblob as varchar(1000) character set utf8) from blobtbl
```

In both cases, the character set clause is optional; it will use the connection character set if left off. Be aware if you use the wrong character set, you might get a transliteration error.